# Used to and would

Tags: would, stative-verbs, used-to

Is the verb "work" a state? For example, the sentence "I used to work as a doctor." is grammatically correct but is "I would work as a doctor." also correct? It doesn't sound weird, is it because it is used as unreal present? The sentence "He would work from 4 am to 7 pm when he was an accountant." is grammatically correct, so does that mean the verb "work" becomes dynamic when it is used in that sentence? Someone please explain, I'm confused.

Comment: "I would work as a doctor" sounds odd to me, because _would_ in this sense usually refers to an action that someone did repeatedly (like your "He would work from 4 am to 7 pm [every day]") .  If the speaker had been in continuous employment, they would be more likely to say "I was working as a doctor [at that time]".

Comment: What do you mean by state or dynamic?

Comment: **Stative** verbs do not normally use the progressive form. Although "He wasn't believing the news" is possible,  it would be more natural to say: "He didn't believe the news" OR "He wouldn't believe the news" OR "He didn't use to believe the news".

Comment: @Gülce ++ The nature of the verb does not change. ++ "*is "I would work as a doctor." also correct?*" Yes, but it is very old-fashioned and usually requires a past time-phrase, e.g. "*When I was younger.*" It was more common about 100 years ago in higher register English. -- I advise that you do not use "would" to mean "used to" today.

Comment: "I work as a doctor" can mean that my profession is a doctor (even if I'm not currently employed), or it can refer to a specific action. Hence it can be stative or not.

Answer (score 1):

USED TO conveys an idea of 'relative permanence and continuity' which WOULD does not in my view.

"I used to work as a doctor and she would call me to ask for advice (often/sometimes/at regular intervals/occasionally, ie with such frequency as to make me remember her action as somewhat repeated, not necessarily permanent or routinary).

I also conceive of the sentence above as implying 'I don't work as a doctor any longer', an element that I regard as essential when it comes to choosing 'USED TO' as opposed to the merely descriptive 'PAST CONTINUOUS').

"I used to work as a doctor" at the time and "she was working" as a shop assistant in a hardware shop in the nearby village (I don't know whether she changed job at some point because I lost track of her years ago)

E&OE, do correct me if you think I'm wrong (I'm not a native speaker/writer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Where are your quotes (?) from? Please cite a source.

Answer (score 0):

Work is not a stative verb.

Furthermore I wouldn’t find the the two sentences synonymous. While both express you worked as a doctor, the latter seems to be emphasizing you only occasionally worked as a doctor. Or depending on context it would be confused with the unreal future.

As a side note it is “use to” not “used to” in that context.

Comment: The clock was working perfectly.

Comment: Sorry, it's _used to_ in all contexts; and it's pronounced funny in all contexts, too -- no [zd] in _used_; you hafta say [st] instead.

Answer (score 0):

Both the sentences are different

Firstly "used to" and "would" are different.

There are 2 meanings of used to which depends on what u want to tell. Like "I'm used to it", where *used* means *accustomed to*.

"I used to go to the beach with my grandparents" where *used* means something you did repeatedly in the past, but not now.

Whereas 'would' is a modal verb with is commonly used to create conditional verb forms. It serves as the past form of will and it indicates repetition in the past. it also express a polite request.

Answer (score 0):

'Used to' covers both continuous/progressive, *and* iterative, past and no longer extant situations:

> We use **used to** when we refer to things in the past which are no longer
> true. It can refer to repeated actions or to a state or situation:
>
> - *That white house over there used to belong to my family.* (It belonged to my family in the past, but not any more.) [continuous
>   aspect]
> - *He used to play football for the local team, but he’s too old now.*
> - [*She used to go fishing most weekends.*] [iterative]

[[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/used-to); modified]

'Would' only covers iterative past actions (and there is sometimes a connotation of willingness and/or geniality, perhaps via 'polite would'. But sometimes, there is more than a hint of exasperation: *He would keep wiping his nose on his shirt sleeve.* Here, 'would' is emphasised in speech.)

> We use **would** to refer to typical habitual actions and events in
> the past. This is usually a formal use and it often occurs in stories
> (narratives):
>
> - I had a friend from Albany, which is about 36 miles away, and we would meet every Thursday morning and she would help us.
> - Then he would wash; then he would eat his toast; then he would read his paper by the bright burning fire of electric coals.

[[again, Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/would)]

OP doesn't have the best terminology and analysis here.

So 'I would work as a doctor' is improbable, though possible in such iterative contexts as

- *She would work as a doctor during the week, and help her father with the farm at weekends*.